# Getting OAuth2 implicit flow to work with Google branding in React

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

In my webapp, my requirements are:

- a 'sign in with Google' button with standard branding
- nothing server-side

I've tried using the `@react-oauth/google` library and I can make a custom button with implicit OAuth2:

```
<button                                                                                
     type="button"                                                                      
     className=""                                                                       
     scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"                               
     onClick={login}                                                                    
>                                                                                      
     <FcGoogle className="" /> Sign in with google                                    
</button>
```

That's great! The code works, except it presents with non-standard branding:

[image: god-awful ugly button]

When I use the standard Google library, I get the full branding, but I can't work out how to use the implicit flow. I've tried using the `@react-oauth/google` handler but the Google javascript supercedes it:

```
      <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>                 
      <div id="g_id_onload"                                                                      
         data-client_id="XXXXXXXXXXX-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
         data-login_uri="http://localhost:3000"                                                  
         data-auto_prompt="false">                                                               
      </div>                                                                                     
      <div className="g_id_signin"                                                               
         onClick={login} // doesn't run, instead uses OAuth2 explicit flow                                                                        
         data-type="standard"                                                                    
         data-size="large"                                                                       
         data-theme="outline"                                                                    
         data-text="sign_in_with"                                                                
         data-shape="rectangular"                                                                
         data-logo_alignment="left">                                                             
      </div>
```

[image: correctly styled Google button]

`@react-oauth/google` will also do the default branded button but I can't work out how to get it to use the implicit flow, either. How do I get the best of both worlds?